# Possible memory leak using the CanvasRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am experiencing a memory leak in my application. I managed to boil it down to a simple test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/729sv/

When adding and removing geometry from a scene, there appears to be a leak.

When the fiddle starts, open a JavaScript console and click on the object a few times. Note the Three.js __objectsRemoved[] array is printed and never goes to 0 (I think this means the garbage collector never removes them).

In a similar fashion, if you use the Chrome Profiles->Record Heap Allocation feature, start the app, click a few times, stop the profile and filter on 'mesh', you'll notice that there are lots of THREE.Mesh's still around as far as the browser is concerned.

If you switch the renderer to a `WebGLRenderer` both of these issues go away.

Is this a bug in the `CanvasRenderer` or am I using it incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the CanvasRenderer. See [ThreeJS garbage collection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715074/threejs-garbage-collection-issue)

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

if ( renderer instanceof THREE.CanvasRenderer ) {

    scene.__lights = { length: 0, push: function(){}, indexOf: function (){ return -1 }, splice: function(){} }
    scene.__objectsAdded = { length: 0, push: function(){}, indexOf: function (){ return -1 }, splice: function(){} }
    scene.__objectsRemoved = { length: 0, push: function(){}, indexOf: function (){ return -1 }, splice: function(){} }

}
```