# ThreeJS garbage collection issue

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, three.js

I have built a ThreeJS app using the canvas renderer (due to project requirements) that I've run into a memory/garbage collection issue with.

Part of the application logic creates a lot of meshes to achieve animations on segments of a flat 2d donut/ring. On each animation pass, we are removing all the previous meshes and generating new ones.

When objects are removed from the scene, they're not deleted from memory but instead, moved to an array called __objectsRemoved. This is kept around indefinitely - I imagine there is some kind of garbage collection that happens to clean everything up eventually but I don't know how to trigger that. The memory usage of the application continuously climbs until it grinds the browser to a halt within 30-40 seconds.

We have not been able to solve this issue and are desperately seeking advice. This project is due for launch for very soon so any immediate guidance/advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is a fiddle that illustrates the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/729sv/

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var base = 0;

init();
animate();

function init() {
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 100;

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', update, false);

    update();
}

function update() {

    if (base) scene.remove(base);

    base = new THREE.Object3D();
    scene.add(base);

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {

        var geometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(50, 3);
        var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        base.add(mesh);
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    console.log(scene.__objectsRemoved.length);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

We are running ThreeJS R62

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you keeping objects around indefinitely? I believe your problem may be coming from the fact that you are storing the 'removed' objects forever. Because you are continually writing to the array, it will never remove anything from it. Either overwrite your values or just plainly discard things.

Comment: Do not create/remove objects in each animation pass. Instead create a pool of objects and reuse them. See, for example, http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_particles_shapes.html

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses.

Justin, I'm actually removing objects, and the library appears to be holding onto deleted items in an array. This is the problem I'm trying to work around.

@WestLangley, I'm generating custom shape geometry for each "tween" of the segments of the donut as they either grow or contract. I'm not sure of a more efficient method to accomplish this but welcome any suggestions.

Comment: If there was a method to create these segments once and then just animate the vertices to expand contract, that would be far more efficient than the current method.

I can post this specific code either here or in another SO post if you'd like to see it.

Comment: I will do my best to answer specific questions about three.js.

Comment: @WestLangley, Thank you. I posted this question in it's own thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722655/threejs-best-approach-to-create-an-animated-2d-segmented-donut-ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the library. Sorry about that :(

I can't believe we haven't hit this until now... `__objectsAdded` and `__objectsRemoved` were added for `WebGLRenderer` for performance reasons. However, we forgot about the side-effects this creates on other renderers (I see you're using `CanvasRenderer`...)

As a workaround... You can try overriding these arrays:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

if ( renderer instanceof THREE.CanvasRenderer ) {

    scene.__lights = { length: 0, push: function(){}, indexOf: function (){ return -1 }, splice: function(){} }
    scene.__objectsAdded = { length: 0, push: function(){}, indexOf: function (){ return -1 }, splice: function(){} }
    scene.__objectsRemoved = { length: 0, push: function(){}, indexOf: function (){ return -1 }, splice: function(){} }

}
```

Comment: thank you! I will give this a try and see if it sorts things out.

Comment: This worked, thanks again for the help on this and all your work on a fantastic library.

Comment: Is this fixed in three.js R66? The workaround created some problems for me.

Comment: Not yet... What problems did it created?