# ThreeJS: Best approach to create an animated 2d segmented donut/ring

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

This is the object I'm using to create a donut with segments that can be animated. There is a method to pass in an array of values to update the segments which then "tweens" to the new values by recreating the widget a bunch of times.

***UPDATE 12/21***

> *This method is causing a memory leak/garbage collection issues. Is there a more performant/efficient method to accomplishing this?*

The memory leak was a seperate issue that was resolved. This post is primarily about finding a more efficient way to generate and animate the geometry for this mesh.

```
donut = function(values, inner_radius, outer_radius) {

    var _inner_radius = inner_radius;
    var _outer_radius = outer_radius;
    var _cur_angle = 0.0;
    var _sector_spacing = (Math.PI * 2) / 150.0;   
    var _container = 0;
    var _cur_values = values.slice(0);
    var _animation_speed = 0.85;

    createWidget(_cur_values);

    function createWidget(values) {

        if ( _container != 0 ) {
            var geometry_for_deletion = [];

            _container.traverse(function (node) {

                if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    geometry_for_deletion.push(node);
                }
            });

            for (var each = 0; each < geometry_for_deletion.length; ++each) {
                geometry_for_deletion[each].parent.remove(geometry_for_deletion[each]);
            }

            geometry_for_deletion = null;
        }
        else {
            _container = new THREE.Object3D();
            _container.name = 'wedge_container';
        }

        var total_value = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            total_value += values[i];
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {

            var angle_1 = _cur_angle;
            var angle_2 = _cur_angle + (values[i] / total_value) *
                                ( Math.PI * 2 - ( values.length ) * _sector_spacing );

            var mesh = createSegment(i,angle_1, angle_2, _inner_radius, outer_radius);
            _container.add(mesh);

            _cur_angle = angle_2 + _sector_spacing;
        }

        scene.add(_container);
    }


    function createSegment(i,begin_angle, end_angle, _inner_radius, outer_radius) {

        var sector_pts = [];

        var num_verts_per_arc = 16;

        for (var j = 0; j < num_verts_per_arc; ++j) {
            var a = begin_angle + (j / (num_verts_per_arc - 1)) * (end_angle - begin_angle);
            var x = outer_radius * Math.cos(a);
            var y = outer_radius * Math.sin(a);
            sector_pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(x, y));
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < num_verts_per_arc; ++j) {
            var a = end_angle - (j / (num_verts_per_arc - 1)) * (end_angle - begin_angle);
            var x = _inner_radius * Math.cos(a);
            var y = _inner_radius * Math.sin(a);
            sector_pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(x, y));
        }

        var sector_shape = new THREE.Shape(sector_pts);

        var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(sector_shape); //, { material: i });
            geometry.name = 'wedge';

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: color,
            overdraw: true
        });

        var segment_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material );

        return segment_mesh;
    }

    this.getParent = function() {
        return _container;
    }

    this.updateValues = function(new_values) {

        if ( new_values.length != values.length ) {
            console.error("Different number of values in update not allowed");
            return;
        }

        var tween_values = _cur_values.slice(0);

        TweenMax.to(
            { val: 0 },
            _animation_speed,
            { 
                val: 1,
                ease: Power3.easeOut,
                onUpdate: function(that,tween_values,_cur_values,new_values) {

                    for(var i=0; i < tween_values.length;++i) {
                        tween_values[i] = _cur_values[i] + ( new_values[i] - _cur_values[i] ) * that.target.val;
                    }

                    createWidget(tween_values);
                },
                onUpdateParams: ["{self}",tween_values,_cur_values,new_values],
                onComplete: function(tween_values,_cur_values) {
                    _cur_values = tween_values.slice(0);
                },
                onCompleteParams: [tween_values,_cur_values]
            }
        );
    }
};
```

Usage is as follows:

```
var mydonut1 = new donut( [20,20,20,20,20], 75, 100 );
mydonut1.updateValues( [30,10,40,10,10] );

var mydonut2 = new donut( [20,20,20,20,20], 75, 100 );
mydonut2.updateValues( [30,10,40,10,10] );
```

Comment: Can you provide a live example? (jsfiddle is best because it is editable)

Comment: @WestLangley, sure thing. I'll post a fiddle link here when it's ready shortly. Thanks

Comment: @WestLangley, here's a fiddle. Any guidance/input is appreciated. Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/droplab/cM6jT/

Comment: You do not have a performance problem, so I would not worry about it. If you were using `WebGLRenderer`, it might be better to have a single ring, and color it with a custom `ShaderMaterial`. Also, `overdraw` is a float now, not a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for the input, much appreciated. Does that mean we can control the amount of overdrawing instead of just a simple on or off?